# Using backbone, can I prevent the nonce from being set?

Tags: rest-api, backbone

I'm using backbone in my website to access the Wordpress API. This works very nicely. However, it is my understanding that backbone *always* sends a nonce with each request.

This appears to be interfering with caching REST responses, as each request, with a nonce, is treated differently.

Is it possible to remove this nonce from the backbone request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the nonce is by default always being sent via the [`X-WP-Nonce` header](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/) – see the source [here](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/6.4/src/js/_enqueues/wp/api.js#L842-L887) and [here](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/6.4/src/js/_enqueues/wp/api.js#L995-L1062) on GitHub.

`wp.api.WPApiBaseModel.prototype.sync` and `wp.api.WPApiBaseCollection.prototype.sync` can technically be extended or modified, but I would instead disable the nonce header like so, i.e. using `<Collection or Model object>.endpointModel`:

- Collection example:

  ```js
  const Posts = new wp.api.collections.Posts();

  // Remove the nonce to disable the X-WP-Nonce header.
  Posts.endpointModel.set( 'nonce', '' );
  //Posts.endpointModel.unset( 'nonce' ); // This also works.

  Posts.fetch( {
      data: { per_page: 2 },
  } ).done(
      data => console.log( data )
  );
  ```
- Model example:

  ```js
  const Post = new wp.api.models.Post( { id: 1 } );

  // Remove the nonce to disable the X-WP-Nonce header.
  Post.endpointModel.set( 'nonce', '' );
  //Post.endpointModel.unset( 'nonce' ); // This also works.

  Post.fetch().done(
      data => console.log( data )
  );
  ```